# Selecting X numeric values farthest from each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select X numbers from a numerically sorted pool of numbers so that each result is as distant in value from every other number as possible.

For example, given:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

For X = 3, it could return: 1,5,9

For X = 5, it could return: 1,3,5,7,9

Comment: What would happen in cases where X-1 isn't a factor of 8?

Comment: @ZLK for my application that will never occur

Comment: In that case, you could do something like the following: `DECLARE @i INT = 3; SELECT TOP (@i) N FROM (SELECT N, MaxN = MAX(N) OVER() FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS T(N)) AS T ORDER BY (N - 1) % ((MaxN - 1) / (@i - 1)), N;` (the key point being how you order the numbers you select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be the answer. Just change the `@x` and `@t`

`@x` is the count of numbers you want

`@t` is the count of consequent numbers in your set

```
declare @x int = 5
declare @t int = 9
;with ct as (
    -- this section is just for generating sequence numbers
    select top (@t) N = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id)
    from sys.tables
)
select N
from ct 
where N % ((@t / @x) + 1) = 1 or N = 1
```

**Sample results for your example**

[image]

[image]

Comment: when significantly more rows are added to the table, this approach does not maximize the distance between the result, the higher values are never returned as results

Comment: @Moonstone, I tried with couple of big numbers like @x = 9 and @t=200. it's still working correctly. do you have any example when the logic fails?

Answer (score 0):

You want the first and last values and then values in-between.  This is something like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by n) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt or
      seqnum % (cnt / nullif((@x - 1, 0))) = 1;
```

Comment: Perhaps `where seqnum % ((cnt - 1) / (@i - 1)) = 1` or `where (seqnum - 1) % ((cnt - 1) / (@i - 1)) = 0`. (I think you need to use a modulo here to get all the in-betweens.)

Comment: this selects mix, max, and middle values only - 3 results